# Accessing a list from a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of length 5, let's say list L has A, B, C, D, E where A is a data frame and all other elements are lists (B,C,D,E). I can access A by using L[['A']]. I cannot access the other elements by using the same syntax.

For example, I want to access list B (list B has a length of 2) from the list L.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a nested `[[` to go inside the elements.  If "B" is a `list` with two elements, use `[[1]]]` after extracting "B"

```
L[["B"]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Or with `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
pluck(L, "B", 1)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
L <- list(A = data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10), B = list(1:3, 1:4),
     C = list(1:2, 4:5), D = list(1:4, 1:2), E = list(1:2, 1))
```